# What does apply and concat means in below nodejs function, and how to use it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to understand apply and concat in below code.
I view https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat
the concat syntax 
is const new_array = old_array.concat([value1[, value2[, ...[, valueN]]]])
Parameters.
But what is purpose of 0 and last parenthesis （）？

```
return extend.apply(undefined, [methodTxObject].concat((0, _toConsumableArray3.default)(extendArgs)));
```

```
var ContractFactory = function ContractFactory(extend) {
  return function (contractABI) {
    var output = {};
    output.at = function atContract(address) {

      function Contract() {
        var self = this;
        self.abi = contractABI || [];
        self.address = address || '0x';

        getCallableMethodsFromABI(contractABI).forEach(function (methodObject) {
          self[methodObject.name] = function contractMethod() {

            if (methodObject.constant === true) {
              throw new Error('A call does not return the txobject, no transaction necessary.');
            }

            if (methodObject.type === 'event') {
              throw new Error('An event does not return the txobject, events not supported');
            }

            var providedTxObject = {};
            var methodArgs = [].slice.call(arguments);

            if (methodObject.type === 'function') {
              if (hasTransactionObject(methodArgs)) providedTxObject = methodArgs.pop();
              var methodTxObject = (0, _assign2.default)({}, providedTxObject, {
                to: self.address
              });

              methodTxObject.function = encodeMethodReadable(methodObject, methodArgs);

              if (!extend) return methodTxObject;

              var extendArgs = methodArgs.slice(methodObject.inputs.length);
              return extend.apply(undefined, [methodTxObject].concat((0, _toConsumableArray3.default)(extendArgs)));
            }
          };
        });
      }

      return new Contract();
    };

    return output;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

An object/array containing functions. It is just a different way to call 
 the `function`. instead of `assigning` and then calling, just get and call `immediate`.

```js
const object = {
  fn: function(name) {
    console.log("My name is: " + name)
  }
}
const fn = object["fn"]

fn("Slim Sheddy") // one way of calling

// OR:

object["fn"]("Slim Sheddy") // other way of calling
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the purpose of the `(0, _fn)` nomenclature, but that's just a function call. The '0,' part somehow changes 'this', and then the function after the comma is called with the arguments. It's basically this:

```
var append = (0, _toConsumableArray3.default)(extendArgs)
// -> something like: _toConsumableArray3.default.call(0?, extendArgs)
var args = [methodTxObject].concat(append)
return extend.apply(undefined, args);
```

It may be a way to avoid prototype inheritance. See:

```
> (0,console.log)('test')
test

> (console.log)('test')
test

> (Object.toString)('test')
'function Object() { [native code] }'

> (0,Object.toString)('test')
Thrown:
TypeError: Function.prototype.toString requires that 'this' be a Function
    at toString (<anonymous>)
```